proxy pass tcp connections based on domains
I have multiple domains set on a server.
Each domain is related to a specific server.
For example :
a.example.com > 192.168.1.10
b.example.com > 192.168.1.11
c.example.com > 192.168.1.12
d.example.com > 192.168.1.13

My clients send requests on ports 8080, 8081, 8082 and ETC and I need to proxy pass these requests to their specific server based on the domain.
as far as I know I cannot use server_name in nginx stream block.
how can I achive this ?
update :

adding server_name in stream blocks in nginx version 1.27.0 dosent
filter requests from specific domain.


Does this answer your question? nginx server_name inside stream block possible?. See also the newer answers there, which suggest that server_name inside a stream block is possible in newer versions of nginx.

i've installed nginx 1.27.0 and added server_name into the stream server block but it was useless and didnt filter domain. tried with 2 different domain and direct ip address and all of them worked.

@HadiH2o did you figure anything out? I am facing the same problem here.
